# Highlight every other list element

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, highlight

I have a div like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ANvpS/. How can I highlight every other list element in the div preferably without using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to perform this is with CSS, for compatible browsers.  Example from [this link](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html):

```
li:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
li:nth-child(odd)  {background: #FFF}
```

Comment: wow thanks! thats super easy. I didn't know css had a selector like that

Comment: Yeah only downfall with using the above is it wont work in IE < 9

Comment: That's likely because, according to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html, IE has never supported this feature until version 9.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/ANvpS/2/

```
var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i = 0; i< listItems.length; i+=2){
     listItems[i].style.background='red';   
}
```